# Non triggering event using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am experiencing a strange issue using jquery. I have a div inside a hidden div. The first event in my script consists to clicj a button to append the div inside the hidden one to a div in the DOM. At this stage, the new div apoending is correctly detected by the chrome inspector. But when I click on it, nothing happens. Here's the code:

```
<div id="toappend" class="class">to append to</div>
<button>button</button>
<div class=invisible>
    <div id="id">hello world</div>
</div> 

<script>

    $('button').click(function{
        $('#toappend').append($('#id'));
    }); 

    $('#id').click(function{
        $('.class').removeClass();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? And you should use `.on()`.

Comment: @11684. `click` is an alias to `on` read the docs for it.

Comment: Yes and no. `.click()` means putting the listeners on the element itself. `.on()` gives you more control. AND: `.click()` was being deprecated I read, while `.on()` is encouraged. @gdoron

Comment: @11684. You're wrong... `:)` I read the docs several times, you're confused with delegate events, and you need to use a selector to make it work that way. Please read the docs... _"In the first two variations, this method (**click**) **is a shortcut** for .bind("click", handler), as well as **for .on("click", handler) as of jQuery 1.7.**"_

Comment: Yes, that's the yes case I mentioned. The no case, is that you can use the `.on()` like this to: `$(".myEls").on("click #myParentel", function() {});` (Not entirely sure about the syntax, but it's possible to do this) This says: "Listen for click events on all `.myEls` that" propagated to `#myParentEl`. The + of this is that it installs only 1 event listener, even if you have 10 `.myEls`. @gdoron

Comment: @11684. That is not the exact syntax but anyway why do you need to use delegate event in **THIS** case? it's working fine without it. see my demo below.

Comment: Yes, it's working. But it will be deprecated (if it isn't already), so that won't last long. Plus, you said that they were the same, so I pointed out they were not, for future readers. @gdoron

Answer (score 4):

You got syntax errors with the functions:

```
$('button').click(function{
$('#id').click(function{
//                     ^------------ missing ()
```

**Should be:**

```
$('button').click(function (){
$('#id').click(function (){
//                      ^ ------------- Here they are.
```

If you looked at the console you would have seen the errors there.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rHADp/)

Comment: Of course! This is what I put in my code(I mistook writing my question(. For sure it still doesn t work!

Comment: No my code is written with function(){...}, but it is not working

Comment: @MehdiBenchoufi. We can't guess, that's the code you pasted, here is the error with it, if you want some other answer, write the full code here, and a http://jsfiddle.net could help even more.

Comment: Copy-pasting is mostly better. Perhaps it is a typo, which you didn't make when you retyped it here. @MehdiBenchoufi